# Error after parallel_for lambda function filling a 2D-vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, for-loop, vector, concurrency

Long story short: I am stuck with some code that throws an error I can't really understand (please have mercy, I am a c++ newbie).
My code (dumbed down) does the following:

```
vector<vector<double>> AmplCo;
AmplCo.resize(1025, vector<double>(65, 0));

Concurrency::parallel_for((long)0, (long)65, [&](long i) {

    for (j = 0; j <= 64; j++)
    {
        PhiRad = double(j) / 128 * PI;
        CosPhi = cos(PhiRad); SinPhi = sin(PhiRad);
        RealCoij = static_cast<double>(RealCo[j * 1025 + i]);
        A = RealCoij * CosPhi;
        B = RealCoij * SinPhi;
        AmplCo.at(i).at(j) =log10(A * A + B * B);
    }

});                  // <- A breakpoint here is reached
RealCo = nullptr;    // <- A breakpoint here is never reached
```

Where `RealCo` is, of course, a pointer.

The execution doesn't reach `RealCo = nullptr;` because between the end of the lambda function and that line, I get an unhandled exception.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: once again, if you want to downvote, at least have some decency to **explain** why.

Comment: Not related and not sure, but I think you can use `0L` for a `(long) 0`

Comment: The indexing `RealCo[j * 1025 + i]` looks like it can go out of bounds

Comment: RealCo is in my example a `0 to 1024 x 0 to 64` bidimensional array passed from outside c++. I'm not sure it ever goes out of bound, since it doesn't throw an error on that line

Comment: Which line throws and what is the exception?

Comment: The end of the lambda function. Editing the answer now to stress this

Comment: doesn't `RealCo[j*1025+i]` can be like `RealCo[j][i]`? also, pleese add the declaretion of **RealCo**.

Comment: No, the RealCo array is passed from VBA as a 1D pointer, so I have to address it like that

Comment: Are you sure it's as big as you think? Check the size of it

Comment: what if you replace the `parallel_for` by a normal for loop, see if that works at least!?

Comment: @doctorlove yes I am sure. Xander, yes it worked before, but I really need to parallelize this stuff, because otherwise it takes a lot of time.

Comment: There's not enough to go on to reproduce this - try setting `RealCoij` to a constant, like 1 in your loop and see what happens. If that's ok, it probably accessing `RealCo` that's the problem. Otherwise that's a clue though I'm not clear what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found out the mistake: multithreading doesn't like much the variables already initialized **before** the `parallel_for`, so I had to set (basically all of) them to private:

```
for (long j = 0; j <= 64; j++)
    {
        double PhiRad = double(j) / 128 * PI;
        double CosPhi = cos(PhiRad); double SinPhi = sin(PhiRad);
        double RealCoij = static_cast<double>(RealCo[j * 1025 + i]);
        double A = RealCoij * CosPhi;
        double B = RealCoij * SinPhi;
        AmplCo.at(i).at(j) =log10(A * A + B * B);
    }
```

The problem was most probably 2 threads accessing `j` at the same time.